# Android App and Library that both use Glide - appPackage1.GlideRequests cannot be cast to appPackage2.GlideRequests

Tags: android, android-library, android-glide, android-module

I'm hoping someone has run into this before and its just an easy setting that i'm missing.  Basically i've built a Kotlin Library that uses Glide, and uses dagger to set up my glide instance in that library.  This library by itself, and in a dummy app works perfect, no issues.

I have an old Java project that i'm testing out using this library in.  Everything seems ok except when I hit the screen with the Glide functionality.  Glide is being used in both the App and the Library and they seem to be colliding.

**This is the error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: appPackage1.Utilities.GlideRequests cannot be cast to appPackage2.di.module.GlideRequests
        at appPackage2.di.module.GlideApp.with(GlideApp.java:88)
```

**In the old Java Application Glide exists as:**

```
@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}
```

**In my Kotlin Library Glide exists as:**

```
@GlideModule
class AppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
```

And it throws the error when it is called like below from my library:

```
GlideApp.with(requireContext()).load
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I needed to dig into the documentation a little closer.

http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#avoid-appglidemodule-in-libraries

> Avoid AppGlideModule in libraries
>
> Libraries must not include AppGlideModule implementations. Doing so
>   will prevent any applications that depend on the library from managing
>   their dependencies or configuring options like Glide’s cache sizes and
>   locations.
>
> In addition, if two libraries include AppGlideModules, applications
>   will be unable to compile if they depend on both and will be forced to
>   pick one or other other.
>
> This does mean that libraries won’t be able to use Glide’s generated
>   API, but loads with RequestOptions will still work just fine (see the
>   options page for examples).

Also a relevant Github Issue on it:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2393

Hopefully if anyone else runs into this, this answer will help.